# Facebook Async load error with another method

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I want to add facebook login to my website. I async load it, and when I check that the person is not logged into my website through facebook I call a function to register them, but I get an error saying my function does not exist... facebook is in an html file, and the method I'm calling (FaceRegister()) is in a javascript file with the same name. I presume this is because of the loading order? Any ideas how to solve this?
Code:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '217518691989396',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.8'
})  ;
FB.AppEvents.logPageView(); 
   $(document).trigger('fbload');
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

$(document).on(
        'fbload',
        function(){
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
 console.log('statusChangeCallback');
 console.log(response);
 // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
 // app know the current login status of the person.
 // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
 // for FB.getLoginStatus().
 if (response.status === 'connected') {
   // Logged into your app and Facebook.
   testAPI();
 } else {
   // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
   faceRegister();
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you including the "FaceRegister.js" File in your html file?

Comment: Yes, methods in that file work fine as long as it's outside the facebook script

Comment: Does it say that statusChangeCallback doesn't exist or that faceRegister doesn't exist?

Comment: It just says faceRegister does not exist... I've tried preloading the script at the start of the html page and still nothing.